# Finding every second element in a repeating pattern

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Data with repeated 'i's followed by 'i's and/or 't's.

```
data = ['i','t','t','i','i','t','t','t']
```

Trying to retrieve the index of the last 't' in the pattern ['i','t','t']:

```
[2,6] // ['i','t','t','i','i','t','t','t'] # position of the returned 't's
      //   _______ ^       _______ ^
```

I'm looking for a non-recursive solution using (pure) functions only, using ramdajs for example.

Tried to use `reduce` and `transduce`, but unsuccessful sofar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to use [`R.aperture`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#addIndex) to iterate over a 3-element sliding window of the `data` list, then tracking the position of any sub-list that equals the pattern `['i', 't', 't']`.

```js
const data = ['i','t','t','i','i','t','t','t']

const isPattern = R.equals(['i', 't', 't'])

const reduceWithIdx = R.addIndex(R.reduce)

const positions = reduceWithIdx((idxs, next, idx) =>
  isPattern(next) ? R.append(idx + 2, idxs) : idxs
, [], R.aperture(3, data))

console.log(positions)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

A point-free version of this approach could look something like the following, though whether this is preferable comes down to a preference of style/readability.

```js
const data = ['i','t','t','i','i','t','t','t']

const isPattern = R.equals(['i', 't', 't'])

const run = R.pipe(
  // create sliding window of 3 elements
  R.aperture(3),

  // zip sliding window with index
  R.chain(R.zip, R.compose(R.range(0), R.length)),

  // filter matching pattern
  R.filter(R.compose(isPattern, R.nth(1))),

  // extract index
  R.map(R.compose(R.add(2), R.head))
)

console.log(run(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nested approach with a temporary array for checking the same pattern for different starting points. This proposal works with an arbitrary length of pattern and returns the index of the predefined pattern.

This solution features obviously plain Javascript.

> ```
> index   i  t  i  t  t  i  i  t  t  t   temp    result    comment
> -----  ------------------------------  ------  --------  ------------
>     0  <i>                             [0]     []        match
>     1   i <t>                          [0]     []        match
>           <->                          [0]     []        no match
>     2   i  t <->                       []      []        no match
>              <i>                       [2]     []        match
>     3         i <t>                    [2]     []        match
>                 <->                    [2]     []        no match
>     4         i  t <t>                 []      [4]       pattern found
>                    <->                 []      [4]       no match
>     5                 <i>              [5]     [4]       match
>     6                  i <->           []      [4]       no match
>                          <i>           [6]     [4]       match
>     7                     i <t>        [6]     [4]       match
>                             <->        [6]     [4]       no match
>     8                     i  t <t>     []      [4, 8]    pattern found
>                                <->     []      [4, 8]    no match
>     9                             <->  []      [4, 8]    no match
>
> <t> matches 't' at position
> <-> does not match at position
> ```

```js
function getPatternPos(array, pattern) {
    var result = [];

    array.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        return r.concat(i).filter(function (j) {
            if (i - j === pattern.length - 1 && a === pattern[i - j]) {
                result.push(i);
                return false;
            }
            return a === pattern[i - j];
        });
    }, []);
    return result;
}

console.log(getPatternPos(['i', 't', 't', 'i', 'i', 't', 't', 't'], ['i', 't', 't']));
// [2, 6]

console.log(getPatternPos(['i','t','i', 't', 't', 'i', 'i', 't', 't', 't'], ['i', 't', 't']));
// [4, 8]

console.log(getPatternPos(['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c']));
// [7]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks. Creative solution, but I don't like the usage of global variables, like `result`.

Comment: @donnut, you yould use a function for it.

Comment: This sequence doesn't work: getPatternPos(['i','t','i', 't', 't', 'i', 'i', 't', 't', 't'], ['i', 't'])

Comment: @donnut, it works as expected, what does not work for this pattern search?

Comment: The result [2,4,8] should be [4,8] because in ['i','t','i', ... the item on position 2 is an 'i' and not a 't'. The question is to find the 't' after a 'i' and a 't'.

Comment: i thought, the pattern must be matched an than take the index after the pattern.

Comment: you could add the wanted last `t` to the pattern array.

Comment: @NinaScholz Crazy! this is such a high-quality answer it's not even funny. However, why do you need to return false in the if statement?

Comment: @Arrow, it removes the starting index out of the temporary array `r`, if the full wanted sequence is found. the first part of the check is to compare the negth and the second is for checking the last item.

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply by `for` loop and check last values of array:

```js
        var data = ['i','t','t','i','i','t','t','t'];
        var positions = new Array();

        for(var i=2; i< data.length; i++){
          if(data[i-2] === 'i' && data[i-1] === 't' && data[i] === 't') {
            positions.push(i)
          }
        }
        
        console.log(positions)
```

Comment: from the question: **_Trying to retrieve the 't' after an 'i' and a 't':_**

Comment: Thanks, but not a functional solution and it has the problem of a negative index in data (e.g. data[0-2])

Comment: Negative index return `undefined` and `if` condition works. `data[-2]` equal to `undefined`.

Comment: There is a difference between just/immediately after and after. Your solution is correct for the latter. @donnut, would be great if you can update  your question to the correct thing needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with a simple condition.

```js
data = ['i','t','t','i','i','t','t','t']


var newData = data.reduce(function (acc, item, index) {
    // Check if current element is `t` and the item before it is `i`, `t` 
    if (item === 't' && data[index - 1] === 'i' && data[index - 2] === 't') {
        acc.push(item)
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newData); // ['t', 't']
```

Comment: This will retrieve every `t` that comes after an `i` not every `t` that comes after an `i` and a `t`.

Comment: This will work, but I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't require the use of indeces. If the first element in the array is a 't', the index is 0 and the data[index-1] will be out of bound. Javascript has no problem with it, but it is not correct.

Comment: The solution from @ScottChristopher avoids indices altogether except to report your results.  That seems a close as you can get unless the real problem involves something more substantial than a list of letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.filter((c, i, d) => c === 't' && d[i - 1] === 't' && d[i - 2] === 'I')
```

**No negative indexes: **

```
const matchMaker = () => {
    let memo = [‘a’, ‘b’];
    return (c, i, d) => {
        memo.unshift(c);
        return memo[1] + memo[2] + c === 'itt';
    }
};

data.filter(matchMaker());
```

Comment: Very elegant solution! If we could only avoid the negative indeces. (I know, it works in javascript, but still)

Comment: Yep, that works (too), although you have the change the return statement to `memo[2]+memo[1]+c === 'itt'` as the memo list is reversed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getPattern(arr, p) {
  var r = [],
    dir = [];
  for (let [i, v] of arr.entries()) {
    dir = dir.concat(i).filter(function(x) {
      if (v === p[i - x] && i - x === p.length - 1) {
        r.push(i);
        return false;
      }
      return v === p[i - x];
    })
  };
  return r;
}

console.log(getPattern(['i', 't', 't', 'i', 'i', 't', 't', 't'], ['i', 't', 't']));
console.log(getPattern(['i', 't', 'i', 't', 't', 'i', 'i', 't', 't', 't'], ['i', 't', 't']));
console.log(getPattern(['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants to see an example without using a library that does not use look ahead or behinds ("`i + 1`" or "`i - 2'`", etc.).

I think it works similarly to what the Ramda approach does, but I chose to combine the partitioning and equality check in the same loop:

- For every step in `reduce`
- Take a section of the array matching the `pattern` length
- Check if it is equal to the pattern
- If it is, add the *index of the last element in the section* to the result of `reduce`

The code, in which `pattern` and `data` are both arrays of strings:

```
const findPattern = (pattern, data) => data.reduce(
  (results, _, i, all) => 
    // Check if a slice from this index equals the pattern
    arrEqual(all.slice(i, i + pattern.length), pattern)
      // Add the last index of the pattern to our results
      ? (results.push(i + pattern.length - 1), results)
      // or, return what we had
      : results, 
    []);

// Utility method to check array equality
const arrEqual = (arr1, arr2) =>
  arr1.length === arr2.length &&
  arr1.every((x, i) => x === arr2[i]);
```

I tested on several data sets and think it meets all requirements:

```js
const findPattern = (pattern, data) => data.reduce(
  (results, _, i, all) => 
    arrEqual(all.slice(i, i + pattern.length), pattern)
      ? push(results, i + pattern.length - 1)
      : results, 
    []);


const arrEqual = (arr1, arr2) =>
  arr1.length === arr2.length &&
  arr1.every((x, i) => x === arr2[i]);
  
const push = (xs, x) => (xs.push(x), xs);

// For just string patterns we could also do:
// const arrEqual = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.join("") === arr2.join("");

// Test cases
const dataSets = [
  // (i) marks a matching index
  // [i] marks a last matching index that should be returned
  //  |  marks a new start

  { pattern: ["i","t","t"], input: ['i','t','t','i','i','t','t','t'],         output: [2, 6] },
  //                               |(0) (1) [2]| 3 -(4) (5) [6]| 7     
  
  { pattern: ["i","t"],     input: ['i','t','i','t','t','i','i','t','t','t'], output: [1, 3, 7] },
  //                               |(0) [1]|(2) [3]| 4 | 5 |(6) [7]| 8 | 9
  
  { pattern: ["i","t","t"], input: ['i','t','i','t','t','i','i','t','t','t'], output: [4, 8] },
  //                               |(0) (1)|(2) (3) [4]| 5 |(6) (7) [8]| 9
  
  { pattern: ["i","t","i"], input: ['i','t','i','t','i','t','i','t','i','t'], output: [2, 4, 6, 8] }
  //                               |(0) (1) [2]|           |(6) (7) [8]| 9
  //                                       |(2) (3) [4]  
  //                                               |(4) (5) [6]  
];

dataSets.forEach(({pattern, input, output}) => 
  console.log(
    "| input:", input.join(" "), 
    "| control:", output.join(", "), 
    "| answer:", findPattern(pattern, input).join(", ")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two years later, lost traveler stumbles upon this question and notices that for variable sized  (and especially large pattern with even larger input array or multiple input arrays), classical [KMP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) would be great.

I think it is worth studing this algorithm.

We will start with simple imperative implementation. Then switch to (at least for me) more intuitive (but probably slightly less optimal, and definitely less optimal when it comes to memory) version with finite automaton. At the end, we'll see something that looks like functional but it is not 100% pure. I wasn't in a mood to torture my self with pure functional implementation of KMP in JS :).

Prefix function KMP, imperative implementation:

```js
function getPatternPos(array, pattern) {
    const result = [];

 // trying to explain this is a waste of time :)

    function createPrefix(pattern) {
     // initialize array with zeros
     const prefix = Array.apply(null, Array(pattern.length)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0);
     let s = 0;
     prefix[0] = 0;

     for (let i = 1; i < pattern.length; ++i) {
   while (s > 0 && pattern[s] !== pattern[i]) {
    s = prefix[s - 1];
   }
   if (pattern[i] === pattern[s]) {
        ++s;
   }
   prefix[i] = s;
     }

     return prefix;
    }

    const prefix = createPrefix(pattern);
    let s = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
  while (s > 0 && pattern[s] !== array[i]) {
   s = prefix[s - 1];
  }
  if (array[i] === pattern[s]) {
   ++s;
  }
  if (s === pattern.length) {
   result.push(i);
   s = 0;
  }
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(getPatternPos(['i', 't', 't', 'i', 'i', 't', 't', 't'], ['i', 't', 't']));
// [2, 6]
console.log(getPatternPos(['i','t','i', 't', 't', 'i', 'i', 't', 't', 't'], ['i', 't', 't']));
// [4, 8]
console.log(getPatternPos(['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c']));
// [7]
console.log(getPatternPos("ababxabababcxxababc".split(""), "ababc".split("")));
// [11, 18]
console.log(getPatternPos("abababcx".split(""), "ababc".split("")));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Finate automaton KMP implementation:

```js
function getPatternPos(array, pattern) {
    const result = [];

    function patternCode(i) {
     return pattern[i].charCodeAt(0);
    }

    function createStateMachine(pattern) {
  // return single dimensional array as matrix instead of array of arrays,
  // for better perfomanse (locality - cache optimizations) and memory usage.
     // zero initialize matrix
     const sm = Array.apply(null, Array(256 * pattern.length)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0);
     let s = 0;
     sm[patternCode(0) * pattern.length + 0] = 1;

     for (let i = 1; i < pattern.length; ++i) {
   // go to same states as if we would go after backing up, so copy all
      for (let code = 0; code < 256; ++code)
    sm[code * pattern.length + i] = sm[code * pattern.length + s];

   // only in case of current symbol go to different/next state
   sm[patternCode(i) * pattern.length + i] = i + 1;

   // update the state that fallows backup path
      s = sm[patternCode(i) * pattern.length + s];
     }

     return sm;
    }

    const sm = createStateMachine(pattern);
    numStates = pattern.length;
 let s = 0;
 // now simply fallow state machine
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
     s = sm[array[i].charCodeAt(0) * numStates + s];
     if (s === pattern.length) {
      result.push(i);
      s = 0;
     }
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(getPatternPos(['i', 't', 't', 'i', 'i', 't', 't', 't'], ['i', 't', 't']));
// [2, 6]
console.log(getPatternPos(['i','t','i', 't', 't', 'i', 'i', 't', 't', 't'], ['i', 't', 't']));
// [4, 8]
console.log(getPatternPos(['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c']));
// [7]
console.log(getPatternPos("ababxabababcxxababc".split(""), "ababc".split("")));
// [11, 18]
console.log(getPatternPos("abababcx".split(""), "ababc".split("")));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Funcational-ish KMP implementation:

```js
function getPatternPos(array, pattern) {
 // pure function that creates state machine,
 // but it's implementation is not complitely pure internally.
 function createStateMachine(pattern) {
  const initState = Object.create(null);
  initState[pattern[0]] = Object.create(initState);

  const  {currState: finalState} = pattern.slice(1).reduce(function(acc, cval, cidx) {
   const newFallbackState = acc.fallbackState[cval] || initState;
   // WARNING: non-functional/immutable part,
   // to make it complitely pure we would probably need to
   // complicate our lives with better data structures or
   // lazy evalutaion.
   acc.currState[cval] = Object.create(newFallbackState);
   return {currState: acc.currState[cval], fallbackState: newFallbackState};
  }, {currState: initState[pattern[0]], fallbackState: initState});

  return {initState: initState, finalState: finalState};
 }

 const {initState, finalState} = createStateMachine(pattern);

 return array.reduce(function (acc, cval, cidx, array) {
  const newState = acc.currState[cval];
  if (typeof newState === 'undefined') {
   return {currState: initState, result: acc.result};
  }
  if (newState === finalState) {
   // WARNING: not purly functional/immutable,
   // still implemenations of JS pure functional/immutable libraries
   // probaly use mutation under the hood, and just make it look pure,
   // this is what happens here also :)
   acc.result.push(cidx);
   return {currState: initState, result: acc.result};
  }
  return {currState: newState, result: acc.result};
 }, {currState: initState, result: []}).result;
}

console.log(getPatternPos(['i', 't', 't', 'i', 'i', 't', 't', 't'], ['i', 't', 't']));
// [2, 6]
console.log(getPatternPos(['i','t','i', 't', 't', 'i', 'i', 't', 't', 't'], ['i', 't', 't']));
// [4, 8]
console.log(getPatternPos(['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c']));
// [7]
console.log(getPatternPos("ababxabababcxxababc".split(""), "ababc".split("")));
// [11, 18]
console.log(getPatternPos("abababcx".split(""), "ababc".split("")));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```